# Как редактировать стили темы у CMS PrestaShop 1.7?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Я прописываю элементарный css код в файл /themes/classic/assets/css/custom.css, сохраняю его, а на сайте ничего не происходит. Этот файл подключен в HTML и при переходе в него из браузера я вижу что он пустой, что там нет моего кода.

Тоже самое касается и файла /themes/classic/assets/css/theme.css. Если его содержимое вовсе удалить, то все равно ничего не произойдет.

Зато если его переименовать в _theme.css, то PS его не найдет и соответственно он не будет подключен в HTML коде.

Все кэширование, вся компиляция и прочее было отключено в админ-панели. В каталоге темы директория cache пустая.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все же редактировать и дополнять CSS код в PS 1.7 версии?

Comment: хм, в принципе за стили отвечают два файла - theme.css и custom.css. Какой браузер вы используете?

Comment: @klifort любой. Какой вам больше нравится - вот тот и использую. Я во всех популярных проверял.

Comment: хм, интересно. У меня в хроме такие дела были. Вот панель настроики кеша из последней престы что делал, и все было ок. http://ivan.gastromi.pro-linuxpl.com/123.jpg

Comment: @klifort я все перепробовал - ничего не помогает. Вот честно. Я тут вопрос зада в состоянии отчаяния.

Comment: @klifort притом как я уже писал, директория cache темы пустая. То есть как бы кэша нет, ну и настройки в админке соответствующие - чтобы ничего жестко не компилировалось и не кэшировалось. Откуда тогда CMS берет стили эти - непонятно.

Comment: У меня только одна мысль по данному поводу - пробуйте чистую установку престы.

Comment: @klifort так я итак на чистой PS сижу. Если вы имеете ввиду повторный перезалив файлов CMS, то уже делал ранее. То есть у меня ничего сверх такого нет. Я взял CMS. Я поставил CMS. Сейчас тупо занимаюсь заполнением контента и пытаюсь решить проблему с темой. Плюс я никаких модулей еще не ставил, ничего. Просто новый контент и редактирование темы - это чем я занимаюсь все это время.

Comment: вы работаете на сервере или локально ? Пробовали и локально и на сервере ? Сорь, за такие вопросы, но интересно почему так выходит, по этому хочу помочь )

Comment: @klifort на сервере. Локально не работаю с CMS.

Comment: Я не предлогаю вам работать с престой локально, но посмотреть будет ли ситуация с стилями повторяться или нет, можна. Также можете попробовать добавить свои css - вот решение - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756398/how-do-i-call-custom-css-in-prestashop-1-7

Comment: @klifort то что по ссылке - неактуально для текущей версии PS. Там это итак прописано. Это я про файлы стилей. Или в том коде что-то иное и я это не увидел?

Comment: На счет актуальности, не вижу. Но все же. Мой совет - попробуйте установить локально и посмотреть измениться стили или нет. Возможно из сервером вопрос, а не из CMS. Прошу без критики просто мысли пишу. Других вариантов не вижу. Так как, я так понял, у вас чистая сборка и проблем не должно быть.

Comment: @k я понимаю. Но не понимаю как сервер может влиять на `css` файлы. Притом на файлы, где чистый `css`.

Answer (score 1):

Все банально просто у меня была такая же проблема просто нужно при каждом редактировании css в браузере нажимать shift + f5 а также чтоб сто процентов очистился кеш переходить в производительность и нажимать значок очистить кеш